# remote: fatal: fsck error in packed object when pushing oh-my-zsh repo to new remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I have installed `oh-my-zsh` and made some local changes I want to push to another `git remote` on `gitlab.com`.

From the GitLab-Docs I tried this:

```
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:alexzeitler/oh-my-zsh-modified.git
```

I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 21586, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8505/8505), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21586/21586), 4.23 MiB | 1.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 21586 (delta 12506), reused 20790 (delta 11901)
remote: error: object 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
remote: fatal: fsck error in packed object
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To gitlab.com:alexzeitler/oh-my-zsh-modified.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:alexzeitler/oh-my-zsh-modified.git'
```

How I can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

[In theory, this was already fixed at GitLab.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/issues/787)  Why it is showing up for you, I have no idea.

The problem here is that `https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh` itself is (somewhat) broken.  This has nothing to do with anything you did.  Meanwhile, your `gitlab.com` service is configured to be ultra-strict.  This *also* **probably** has nothing to do with anything you did—but you'll need to change it, or else give up on the idea of sending *this* repository to `gitlab.com`.  (Or, perhaps your best bet, get them to note that their fix has un-fixed itself.)

If you clone the URL above and run `git fsck` on your own clone, you'll see this:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
warning in tree 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
warning in tree a18c4d13c2a5fa2d4ecd5346c50e119b999b807d: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
warning in tree 84df066176c8da3fd59b13731a86d90f4f1e5c9d: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
Checking objects: 100% (21666/21666), done.
```

Git is of course correct:<sup>1</sup>

```
$ git cat-file -p 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6
100644 blob f84db6dc27af34f9f8e393f39a8aedf04ef86c0d    .gitignore
100644 blob 950f8861bc7ecbc25cd3544bf33e71cfb04a1ae7    README.textile
040000 tree 30b4ef0a0656cc9e2cfd4140a794bc018ab9e7d0    custom
040000 tree 4a22e953b9b4c774b13f78e157cb2f2b994e7b82    functions
040000 tree 56dccf6298605f85fc44025a0135e2dd796c1be9    lib
040000 tree 44f5974bb55c300d23cd39e96b1f7df57c4f9457    log
100644 blob eadf02d00fb0b625f58bd4ef2ea8dd56bcc85aef    oh-my-zsh.sh
040000 tree 5ffecc5c15dc9c3458de787e93135da481094717    templates
040000 tree 8a2c7f00e3c74ed417ce7458942b90ba56f4aeed    themes
040000 tree d6621bc3b6b3f5d6f70b119bade00a7d39494695    tools
```

All of those entries that read `040000` should read `40000`.  Git's internal object format requires that `mode` entries *not* be zero-padded on the left.

What *that* means is that whatever *created* this repository, created one that violates the rules.  However, as you can see from my own `git fsck` output, this particular rules-violation draws a *warning*, not an outright error, from `git fsck`.

Whenever you set up a Git server, e.g., by creating `gitlab.com` and selling it to users, you get to choose how to control the `git config` variables in new repositories you create.  It's up to you, or in this case them—the people controlling `gitlab.com`—to do this.  Whoever they are, they've set the control knobs to be stricter than the defaults.  (See also [this 2014 notice](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/12/24/gitlab-update-for-git-vulnerability/).)

[The `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) says this about [`receive.fsckObjects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receivefsckObjects):

> If it is set to true, git-receive-pack will check all received objects. See `transfer.fsckObjects` for what’s checked. Defaults to false. If not set, the value of `transfer.fsckObjects` is used instead.

Meanwhile [the `transfer.fsckObjects` section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-transferfsckObjects) reads, in part:

> When `fetch.fsckObjects` or `receive.fsckObjects` are not set, the value of this variable is used instead. Defaults to false.
>
> When set, the fetch or receive will abort in the case of a malformed object or a link to a nonexistent object. In addition, various other issues are checked for, including legacy issues (see `fsck.<msg-id>`), and potential security issues like the existence of a `.GIT` directory or a malicious `.gitmodules` file (see the release notes for v2.2.1 and v2.17.1 for details). Other sanity and security checks may be added in future releases.
>
> On the receiving side, failing fsckObjects will make those objects unreachable, see "QUARANTINE ENVIRONMENT" in [git-receive-pack[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack). On the fetch side, malformed objects will instead be left unreferenced in the repository.

If you can disable `receive.fsckObjects` (and/or if it's set, `transfer.fsckObjects`, but the GitLab notice I linked suggest that they merely always set `receive.fsckObjects`), you can open yourself to potential vulnerabilities<sup>2</sup> and hence push this malformed repository onward.  Or, if you can set `receive.fsck.skipList`, you can list those three specific malformed `tree` objects so that GitLab can continue to look for potential vulnerabilities while you declare that these three trees are harmless.  Or, if you can set `fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode ignore` or `receive.fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode ignore`, that too would fix the problem.

Whether and how you can set these, I have no idea: if you could log in directly to `gitlab.com` you could `cd` to your own repository and run `git config`, but obviously you can't.  Your final option is to convince everyone who uses robbyrussel's repository to fix up their repository with a new corrected one.  That, however, is painful for everyone else.

---

<sup>1</sup>The demonstration here is suspect: `git cat-file -p` normalizes the tree output, so this doesn't really show the problem.  `git cat-file tree <hash>` gets the raw data, but a tree is full of binary data (of variable length!) and is therefore hard to observe.

<sup>2</sup>The actual risk here is pretty low: it's *old* versions of Git, not the ones on GitLab itself, that are vulnerable.  What GitLab is doing here is saying, in effect, *We only store the highest quality repositories, not the ones with dodgy stuff that, for all we know, might be in there in order to break into **your** computer when you clone a repository.*  If you run up-to-date versions of Git, you are, presumably, not vulnerable either, so the protection GitLab is selling you here is something you already own anyway.  But if you run old dodgy versions of Git, you can buy GitLab's protection, rather than updating your old dodgy Git.